# Error while installing linkGrabber using pip

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, pip, x86-64, cl

I am trying to install linkGrabber using pip. I am using python 3.5 and have downloaded Microsoft Visual 2015 as well.
I keep getting this error

[snapshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJHYn.png)

```
*creating Users\HPPAVI~1\AppData\Local\Temp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /TcC:\Users\HPPAVI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit3564bx89.c /FoUsers\HPPAVI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit3564bx89.obj
    xmlXPathInit3564bx89.c
    C:\Users\HPPAVI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit3564bx89.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\users\hp pavilion\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\HPPAVI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-6e_3b7yo\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\HPPAVI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-_tutb08l-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\HPPAVI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6e_3b7yo\lxml\*
```

what should I do?

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Copy and paste the error into a code block in your question.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I pasted the error code!